# Create a Chrome extension show content on a page and invisible in inspect element

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, textarea, web-inspector

I want to write a Chrome extension that adds a button to the corner of every `textarea` element and shows an alert after a click on it. So I checked some alike extensions like Grammarly, and I noticed that it doesn't create any element on a page. So my question is:  how can I write something like this?

I tried to do this by adding some button in the `content.js` that unfortunately adds the element to the page and shows up in inspect mode.

**content.js:**

```
const btn = document.createElement('button')
btn.textContent = "Okay"
btn.onclick = function() { alert('blah'); };
document.documentElement.append(btn)
```

**Example of what I want:**

[image: example]

Comment: If you want to append it to textarea you first have to select that textarea. At the moment you are appending it to the root of the document.

Comment: @Michel, My problem is somewhere else. I want to don't show this in inspect mode like Grammarly extension.

Comment: `"So I checked some alike extensions like Grammarly, and I noticed that it doesn't create any element on a page."` - Really? https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrFlr.png

Comment: Thank you @Turnip, the tag was somewhere else and I couldn't find that. Now i find it!

Comment: Right Click > Inspect Element

Comment: Grammarly creates a DOM element, the only "trick" is that it puts the UI inside ShadowDOM, see a tutorial if needed.